# Como somar DateTime.Time no Pandas por group by?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dataframe com duas colunas de Total CPU Time e Date, no formato abaixo:

```
Total Cpu Time: 00:00:14
Date : 2019-02-06
```

Preciso fazer um group by por Date que some as horas (sem desprezar minuto e segundo) do CPU Time. Tentei converter do jeito abaixo e depois dar group by, mas sem sucesso.

```
df['total_cpu_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['total_cpu_time']).dt.time
```

Alguém possui uma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode converter em datetime e timedelta e depois fazer groupby() e sum(). Para o plot é preciso converter em segundos.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = { 'Total Cpu Time': ['00:00:14', '00:00:15', '00:00:16', '00:00:17'], 'Date': ['2019-02-07', '2019-02-07', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-08'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Total Cpu Time', 'Date']) 

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Total Cpu Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Cpu Time'])

grouped = df['Total Cpu Time'].groupby(df['Date']).sum()
print(grouped)

grouped.astype('timedelta64[s]').plot.bar(x='Date', y='Total Cpu Time', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maravilha! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Como eu plotaria este resultado? Ele dá erro de "No numeric data to plot".

Comment: Editei a resposta.